# Масштабирование dp Андроидом

Tags: android

К примеру есть кнопка:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin=""@dimen/btn_margin"
    />
```

Есть dimen.xml (values-xxhdpi):

```
<dimen name="btn_margin">16dp</dimen>
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что Андроид сам сделает нужный размер под экран устройство исходя из btn_margin для xxhdpi ?

Т.е. для экрана устройство с плотностью mdpi Андроид сделает размер `btn_margin/3=16/3=5.3` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, он возьмет этот размер (габарит), только если ваш device будет соответствовать условию, которое вы выставили для этой папки xxhdpi > 480 dpi (более чем), если не существует след. папки xxxhdpi это > 640 dpi.

> Но это не работает в обратном порядке

, поэтому в вашем случае, если device не соответствует условию (модификатора папки ресурсов), то значения будут взяты по default из корневой "values" dimen.xml.

Если вы хотите, чтоб для всех устройств использовался dimen = 16dp, вам необходимо убедится, что у вас существует только один экземпляр файла  dimens.xml и он лежит в корневой папке values. ( не values-xxhdpi как в вашем примере)

Comment: А как мне указать один размер и чтобы андроид опираясь на него умножал(делил) его под определенный экран ? Указать в корневой папке размер для mdpi ?

Comment: мне кажется Вам будет полезно подробней понять единицы измерения android. вкратце "dp" ставит размер относительно плотности экрана, это очень сильно упрощает работу. Вы не разу не задумывались, как меняются размеры когда вы переходите из landscape в portrait mode? Поэтому если у вас в папке values стоит dimen 16dp то в mdpi это 16px, те же самые 16dp на xhdpi это 32px.
Получается, что имея один параметр ваша кнопка будет одинаково выглядеть на разных устройств (ну не совсем), тема очень обширная, поэтому буду советовать почитать это на оф источнике.

Comment: Я понимаю, что dp это относительная единица измерения. Для hdpi это mdpi х 1.5 и тд. Я не хочу делать несколько файлов dimens для разных плотностей, а указать в одном файле(к примеру, с квалификатором mdpi, т.е. обычному values) и чтобы Андроид потом сам умножал значение из этого файла под нужный экран. Или же все таки надо делать под каждый квалификатор(values-mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi) ?

Comment: если вы хотите чтоб на другом devicr demin имел иное значение (те габариты были иные) вам придется создать values-mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi/xxhdpi) иначе как app поймет что необходимо сменить значение? и убедитесь что name везде одинаков.

Comment: "имел иное значение" - в плане значение, которое нельзя высчитать исходя из начального ? могу я задать только одно значение с плотностью mdpi, андроид сам высчитает значение для, к примеру, xxhdpi(т.е. умножит на 3) ?

Comment: ну конечно, как и написано в ответе. Наверное я плохо объяснил, сейчас дополню.

Comment: Спасибо за детальный ответ!!